# In sqoop what does "size" mean when used with --split-limit arguments

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2

[From sqoop docs](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/sqoop-1.4.6-cdh5.10.1/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism)

> Using the --split-limit parameter places a limit on the size of the split section created. If the size of the split created is larger than the size specified in this parameter, then the splits would be resized to fit within this limit, and the number of splits will change according to that.

What does "size" refer to here. Can some one explain with a little example.

Comment: Sqoop creates a number of mapreduce jobs. Input splits, perhaps? Size commonly expressed in MB

Comment: that's my first guess either. But `--split limit` is passed as a parameter while importing. And this is what bothered me. Size of what? The split size of RDBMS table being imported. Then this is something sqoop will not know I guess? So the question still remains a question for me.

Comment: Rdbms tables are scanned by their index columns or row count,  I believe. Sqoop will calculate that, distribution and create mappers and reducers for each split section

Comment: I think you are skipping over the part that says "User can override the --num-mapers by using --split-limit option.", meaning,  the size is controlling the number   of mappers

Comment: @cricket_007, can you be little more clear or post an answer(i will appreciate) . I am only, for the moment, bothered about what "size" means and if it's table size (is it number or rows or the size of data in the table) how does sqoop figure it out.

Comment: This is to define how many mappers you want to run to execute your job.By default no of mappers =4 ,sqoop it runs max and min query finds total of data to be imported divides it between mappers.But what if you wanted to override query and split as per your understanding thats where --split-by kicks in,considering if you have uneven distribution of split column default query leads to uneven load on mappers not improving performance. When you define size in split-by you are explicitly giving size of split should be on which each mapper will work and accordingly number of mapper will be set

Comment: Also from the sqoop docs for `--split-limit` => _Upper Limit for each split size. This only applies to Integer and Date columns. For date or timestamp fields it is calculated in seconds._

Comment: I specified `--split-limit 500,000` - (comma for readability). In execution **Sqoop** Says `Split size: 493,714,285`  Like 500 MB? Now  `sqoop help` says -  `Upper Limit of rows per split for split columns of Date/Time/Timestamp and integer types. ...` Here there is a discrepancy It says rows - but when I am checking a mapper it is fetching 5,474,182 rows.

Answer (score 2):

I was just reading this and I think it would be interpreted like this.
Example table has a Primary Key col called ID and is an INT and table has 1000 rows with the ID values from 1 to 1000. if you set num-mappers to 50 then you would have 50 tasks each try to import 20 rows. The first query would have a predicate that says WHERE ID >= 1 AND ID <= 20. The 2nd mapper would say WHERE ID >= 21 AND ID <= 40... and so on.

If you also define the split-limit then depending on the size of the splits this parameter may adjust the number of tasks used to sqoop the data.
For example, with num-mappers set to 50 and split-limit set to 10, you would now need 100 tasks to import 10 rows of data each to get all 1000 rows. Your first task would now saw WHERE ID >= 1 AND ID <= 10.

In the case of a DateTime column, the value is now based on seconds. So If you have 10 years of data with 1 row for every day you would have about 3,653 rows of data. If you set num-mappers to 10 then your tasks would each try to sqoop about 365 days of data with a predicate that looked something like MYDATETIMECOL >= '2010-01-01' AND MYDATETIMECOL <= '2010-12-31' but if you also set the split-limit to something like 2592000 (num of seconds in 30 days) then you would need about 122 tasks to sqoop the data and the first task would have a predicate like MYDATETIMECOL >= '2010-01-01' AND MYDATETIMECOL <= '2010-01-30'.

These two examples have both used a 1:1 ratio for column value to row count. If either of these tables had 1000 rows per value in the split-by col then ALL of those rows would be sqooped as well.

Example with DateTime col where every day you have loaded 1000 rows for the last 10 years and now you have 3,653,000 rows, the predicates and the number of tasks would be the same but the number of rows sqooped in each of those tasks would be 1000x more.